# Jquery Mobile - jumping fixed header after closing dialog (firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

i have a problem, you can see that here (with firefox) : http://fiddle.jshell.net/ckuskun/qrcdS/show/light/

when click to "open" link, a dialog is opening. after closing this dialog, fixed header is jumping to the top.

how can i fix this problem

i'm having this problem mac firefox and windows firefox, no problem with other browsers. I have tried both as local and hosting.

http://www.screenr.com/BVhH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery Mobile bug and it is related to dialog's and how framework is handling page back action.

For now it can be fixed if you remove **`data-position="fixed"`** from a first page header.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/A5Tp8/5/embedded/result/

**HTML :**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="yonetim">
    <div data-role="header" id="fheader">
        <h1>lorem</h1>          
    </div><!--header-End-->
    <div data-role="content">       
        <a href="#yeni-kullanici-ekle" data-prefetch="true" data-theme="a" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" >open</a>              
    </div><!--content-End-->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="border-top:1px solid #aaa;">
        <h6 id="footer-text"><a href="<?=BASE_URL; ?>/Anasayfa/CikisYap/" data-ajax="false" >log-out</a> - </h6>
    </div><!--footer-End--> 
</div><!--page-End-->



<div data-role="dialog" id="yeni-kullanici-ekle"  data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Yeni Kullanıcı</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
            deneme
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">     
            deneme
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My advice would be to replace dialog with a overlay popup. You can get almost same effect.